# I am getting SDK build tools not found error while building my AR Project in Unity editor even after putting the correct path in unity 2021.3.4f1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, game-development, android-augmented-reality

[image]

I am getting a unity error while trying to build my vuforia AR project. pls check out

Answer (score 1):

If you open Unity Hub and go to the "Installs" section you will be able to make the appropriate modifications to your unity installation. Once that is done your unity version should also show the android icon below meaning that you have installed and can now build for android!

Most of the pre-requisites for that are installed by Unity automatically, including the paths, however it would be a good idea to make sure that there are no conflicts.

You should also fill in the checkboxes once you have the appropriate versions! [image: Adding new Modules in unity]

Comment: thankyou but i'm not getting add modules option in my unity hub

Comment: i was't able to download my unity editor from hub so I downloaded from unity website 
and the android module was also downloaded from it's website but than I was getting an error of "SDK directory does not exist " event after downloading the correct android module from unity website

Comment: I think Unity Hub is the best way to actually do this, considering that the SDKs are also recommended by Unity. It will generally save you a lot of trouble. As far as I am aware you can also do it the manual way but you need to be careful with which version of the SDK you install and which version is the best for your current unity version etc. 

There doesn't seem to be much of a drawback to do it through unity hub considering you can simply add your current unity version inside the hub and it will register it in there! 

I think there is also a way to add modules in the Build Settings

Comment: no, I did not find a way to add modules in the unity hub and I don't know how to add modules.

Comment: Have you entered the "Installs" Section in Unity Hub? Can you see your Unity Version in the Hub?

Comment: yes Fortis i can see the installs button in Unity Hub and I checked the gear icon at the top right corner but there was the no option of adding modules in my unity editor

Comment: Turns out that according to this https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/GettingStartedAddingEditorComponents.html

You cannot add modules unless the editor was installed inside the Hub

Comment: yes that's the problem I don't know that is there a bug that is not allowing me to install the unity editor from my hub
so I had to install it from unity archives